# MySQL SELECT with decimal values

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, decimal

I'm trying to select a row from `MySQL` table that contains DECIMAL values.

When I call:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table WHERE  submit_time='1386163272.2866' LIMIT 1
```

it selects the row properly. But when I try to make this select a little bit more specific:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table  WHERE  submit_time='1386163272.2866' AND field_name='stan' LIMIT 1
```

it returns no results.

The `submit_time` field is `DECIMAL(16,4)` and `field_name` is `VARCHAR`. Of course there is a row with that combination of submit_time/field_name values (I checked via phpmyadmin)

Where did I go wrong?

**EDIT:**

The query:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table  WHERE  field_name='stan'
```

also returns a row.

Using [Vincent's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20386696/177167) following query:

```
SELECT * FROM some_table  WHERE  submit_time='1386163272.2866' AND field_name LIKE '%stan%' LIMIT 1
```

returned the row that I wanted, but I now want to update some values in this row, so I'm trying following query:

```
UPDATE some_table SET field_value='1' WHERE  submit_time='1386163272.2866' AND field_name LIKE '%stan%' LIMIT 1
```

but it says "no row affected".

**SOLUTION**

OK, when I removed the `'` from `WHERE` query, it worked:

```
UPDATE some_table SET field_value='1' WHERE  submit_time=1386163272.2866 AND field_name LIKE '%stan%' LIMIT 1
```

Comment: It is such an easy query, that it's hard to do anything wrong. Try the same query in phpMyAdmin. Does it work?

Comment: Nope, that's the problem.

Comment: Can you make an sqlfiddle. This looks really weird.

Comment: Make sure the value displayed in phpMyAdmin is actually what you think it is. Perhaps the actual value has an extra space `'stan '` or something else that is causing the confusion.

Comment: @user4035 - no, I can't, the website is currently down.

Comment: @diolemo - I checked - no extra spaces ets...

Comment: @Gacek See it :(. Mabe, you can put CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements inside your post?

Comment: are you really sure there is a row that match?

Comment: SELECT * FROM table WHERE field_name='stan' does it return any results?

Comment: @Mihai -  yes, it does.

Comment: Queries giving wrong results are usually symptoms of table corruption. Are you using MyISAM engine? You may want to do `CHECK TABLE some_table`.

Comment: @piotrm - `check status OK`

Comment: Does `field_value` already have a value of 1?

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing

```
field_name='stan'
```

to

```
field_name LIKE '%stan%'
```

To identify if there is any whitespace in the 'field_name' field. Then fix it from there.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but now I have some problems with updating this table - see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

If submit_time is an double datatype then you should select it as an double type like this

```
SELECT * FROM some_table  WHERE  submit_time=1386163272.2866
```

And not as varchar / char like you are doing (MYSQL's implicit typecasting is nasty and this "feature" will cost you performance if MySQL cant use an index because off this)
This query below is not really what you want to use

```
SELECT * FROM some_table  WHERE  submit_time='1386163272.2866'
```

And for your whitespace problem (UPDATES all field_value columns in your table)

```
UPDATE some_table SET field_value = TRIM(field_value);
```

Comment: Thanks, It seems that it just took to remove the `'`s from query.

Comment: @Gacek you may want to consider to use an TRIM function in your PHP application http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php so your column cant be "infected" again..